# SpringData MongoDb Repository FindObject List Field by List

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to find a specific Entity based on its Listed Values. However the following query does not work, anybody has any idea what I am doing wrong? Example below?

Note: The database in use is mongodb
Database and Models look like the example below:

```
Entity1{
  name: x
  options:[
    {
     id: 1
     key: value1,
     someOtherKey: someOtherValues
     },
    {
     id: 2
     key: value2,
     someOtherKey: someOtherValues2
     }
  ]
}

Entity2{
  name: x
  options:[
    {
     id: 4
     key: value4,
     someOtherKey: someOtherValues4
     },
    {
     id: 5
     key: value5,
     someOtherKey: someOtherValues5
     }
  ]
}
```

Model

```
public class Entity {
  
  private String name;

  @DBRef
  private List<Option> options;

}
```

I want get Entity2, my parameter is, list:

```
options:[
 {
   id: 4
   key: value4,
   someOtherKey: someOtherValues4
 },
 {
   id: 5
   key: value5,
   someOtherKey: someOtherValues5
 }
]
```

My repository:

```
List<Entity> findByValues(List<Option> options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `ElementCollection`. You can use it like this:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
  
  private String name;

  @ElementCollection
  private List<Values> values;

}
```

And there is an [example](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/), if you want to learn more.

Comment: I'm using MongoDb

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a `list<Value>` that is a list of all values from your Json Array `values`, for example from your Json Array called `values`

```
values:[
    {key1: value1}
    {key3: value2}
  ]
```

you can get List that includes all values like `value1, value2, ...` and let's say it is a `List<Value>`, then in your **repository**, you can use something like

**1) Using Spring data specification**

```
List<Value> findByValuesIn(List<Value> values);
```

**2) Using Native Query**

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.values IN (:values)")
List<Employee> findByValues(@Param("values") List<Value> values);
```

Comment: The database in use is MongoDb. Also the valuesSection is an example of an object list/collection. I updated the example to be more realistic to my situation. I hope its clearer.

Comment: Try 
`List<Entity> findByValuesIn(List<Option> options);`
instead of 
`List<Entity> findByValues(List<Option> options);`